# python: getting UnicodeEncodeError when trying to parse a list

Tags: python, unicode, ascii

trying to pipe a list that I've scraped from http://www.ropeofsilicon.com/roger-eberts-great-movies-list/ through the API at http://www.omdbapi.com/ to grab their IMDB ids.

creating logging for movies that I can and can't find as follows:

```
import requests

OMDBPath = "http://www.omdbapi.com/"

movieFile = open("movies.txt")
foundLog = open("log_found.txt", 'w')
notFoundLog = open("log_not_found.txt", 'w')

####

for line in movieFile:
    name = line.split('(')[0].decode('utf8')
    print name
    year = False
    if line.find('(') != -1:
        year = line[line.find('(')+1 : line.find(')')].decode('utf8')
        OMDBQuery = {'t': name, 'y': year}
    else:
        OMDBQuery = {'t': name}

    req = requests.get(OMDBPath, params=OMDBQuery)
    if req.json()[u'Response'] == "False":
        if year:
            notFoundLog.write("Couldn't find " + name + " (" + year + ")" + "\n")
        else:
            notFoundLog.write("Couldn't find " + name + "\n")
    # else:
    #     print req.json()
    #     foundLog.write(req.text.decode('utf8').encode('latin1') + ",")
movieFile.close()
foundLog.close()
notFoundLog.close()
```

Been reading a lot about unicode encoding and decoding, looks like this is happening because I'm not encoding the file in the right manner? Not sure what's wrong here, getting an issue when I get to "Caché":

```
Caché
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 34, in <module>
    notFoundLog.write("Couldn't find " + name + " (" + year + ")" + "\n")
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 18: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: I've read through that response and I'm not certain that it helps me in my case here. Adding `.encode('ascii', 'ignore')`, for instance, converts 8½ to 8. I'm looking to preserve the maximum amount of fidelity to give me something to search by while also letting me write output to a file.

Comment: I think what you want is `name.encode('utf-8')`.

Comment: now getting `UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)` when I get to 8 1/2

Comment: for line in movieFile:
    name = line.split('(')[0]
    name = name.encode('utf-8')
    print name

Comment: Sorry, I meant that you should be calling `name.encode('utf-8')` when you try to write to the log file, not when you read from `movies.txt`.

Comment: ok now I'm back to my original error when I get to caché: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 35, in <module>
    notFoundLog.write("Couldn't find " + name.encode('utf-8') + " (" + year.encode('utf-8') + ")" + "\n")
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 4: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56914/discussion-between-fox-and-dano).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working solution that relies on the [`codecs`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html) module to provide transparent encoding/decoding to/from `utf-8` for the various files you open:

```
import requests
import codecs

OMDBPath = "http://www.omdbapi.com/"

with codecs.open("movies.txt", encoding='utf-8') as movieFile, \
     codecs.open("log_found.txt", 'w', encoding='utf-8') as foundLog, \
     codecs.open("log_not_found.txt", 'w', encoding='utf-8') as notFoundLog:
    for line in movieFile:
        name = line.split('(')[0]
        print(name)
        year = False
        if line.find('(') != -1:
            year = line[line.find('(')+1 : line.find(')')]
            OMDBQuery = {'t': name, 'y': year}
        else:
            OMDBQuery = {'t': name}

        req = requests.get(OMDBPath, params=OMDBQuery)
        if req.json()[u'Response'] == "False":
            if year:
                notFoundLog.write(u"Couldn't find {} ({})\n".format(name, year))
            else:
                notFoundLog.write(u"Couldn't find {}\n".format(name))
        #else:
            #print(req.json())
            #foundLog.write(u"{},".format(req.text))
```

Note that the use of the `codecs` module is only required in Python 2.x. In Python 3.x, the built-in `open` function should handle this properly by default.